# JQuery. need help thinking through how to build dynamic fields related to a previous dynamic field

Tags: jquery

This page allows users to add questions dynamically (this part works), within each question a user can add one to many answers which are also dynamic. Here's a wire frame of the page which might help: https://gomockingbird.com/mockingbird/#2ql43kg/0W2gD1

As I said, the question part is done and the fields are being posted from the form correctly.

I need some help thinking through how to go about adding the answer area. Here is my code thus far.

```
<script>
currentQuestion = 1;

 function addQuestion(){
// Clone our question container and assign it a new ID
var newElement = $('#questionContainer0').clone().attr('id','questionContainer'+currentQuestion);
// Update the ID and Name of the textarea in our question container
newElement.children('#question0').attr('id','question'+currentQuestion).attr('name','question'+currentQuestion);
// Append our new question container to the bottom
newElement.appendTo('#questionArea');

currentQuestion++;
}

function addAnswer(){
//var newAnswer = $('#question0-answer1').clone().attr('id','question0-answer2').attr('name','question0-answer2');
//newAnswer.appendTo('#answerContainer0');
}
</script>
</head>

<form method="post" action="test.cfm">
<div id="questionArea">
<div id="questionContainer0" class="questionContainer">
    <textarea id="question0" name="question0"></textarea>
    <div id="answerContainer0">
    <input type="text" id="question0-answer1" name="question0-answer1" />
    <p><a href="#" onClick="addAnswer();" id="add">Add Answer</a></p>
</div>  
</div>

<input type="submit" value="go" name="submit">
</form>
<a href="#" onClick="addQuestion();" id="addQuestion" title="Add a question" class="link-sm" style="background-color:red;">Add Question</a>
```

FWIF, I am new to JQuery and if how I am approaching this is wrong entirely, please let me know :) - I am sure there is a slicker way to do it without writing an addQuestion function and calling it with an onClick.

Comment: A little aside from your question, but really nice UI!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it this way:
First, change your addAnswer link html to the following:

```
<a href="javascript:" class="add-answer">Add Answer</a>
```

Your script would be this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".add-answer").click(function(){ //bind a click event
       addAnswer($(this));
   });
});

function addAnswer($anchor){
  var questionId = $anchor.siblings("textarea").attr("id");
  var answerIndex = $anchor.siblings(":text").size() + 1;
  var answerId = questionId + "-answer" + answerIndex;
  var $lastAnswer = $anchor.siblings(":text:last");
  $lastAnswer.clone().attr("id", answerId).attr("name", answerId).insertAfter($lastAnswer); //Changed this line
}
```

And I'd remove the `currentQuestion` global var and change the addQuertion function also:

```
function addQuestion(){
  var curentQuestion = $(".questionContainer").size(); //Number of questionContainers
  var $newElement = $('#questionContainer0').clone().attr('id','questionContainer'+currentQuestion);
  $newElement.children('#question0'). attr('id','question'+currentQuestion).attr('name','question'+currentQuestion);
  //Update the answerContainer div id.
  $newElement.children('#answerContainer0') .attr('id','answerContainer'+currentQuestion);
  //Update the first answer id and name
  var answerId = 'question'+currentQuestion+'-answer1';
  $newElement.children('#question0-answer1').attr('id',answerId).attr('name',answerId);
  $newElement.appendTo('#questionArea');
}
```

And that's it. If you have doubts, just ask me.
Hope this helps. cheers

Comment: Edgar, thanks so much - Your changes were really insightful. I have a lot to learn.

The questions are working still but the answers are not. I'm getting no result when clicking the link :(

Comment: You're welcome. Are you getting a javascript error? Could you please upload the code to jsfiddle.net, so I can correct it there?

Comment: I found an eror in my code. I'm editing my answer (wrote `.after` instead of `.insertAfter`. If it doesn't work still, please upload to jsfiddle

Comment: So awesome man, thank you. I see one thing wrong. When I add some answers to question one, and then click add new question, the new question starts with the # of answers of the previous. Sick work though, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Could you please mark my answer as correct (green check)?. PS: If you need help with that last issue, just tell me :)

Comment: Hi Edgar, definitely - I think I need to sign up to do that, so I will!  I just tried to run a few tests and found that if I add more than 2 questions, the name's of the third set and beyond are not passed through the form (weird).  Additionally, it seems to not clear the answers properly when cloning. Would love your assistance in getting the last issues wrapped up. I'll signup now to green check you! thanks again

Comment: I'll help you in some hours please, i'm sleepy. It's 4am in Bolivia hehe. Is it ok? Or is it urgent?

Comment: Not urgent - thanks again! I'll check in the morning (1 am here) :)

Comment: edgar thanks so much my friend. the ui works perfectly. i'm still getting some strange behavior when posting the form. it appears the first answer for question 2 is appending itself to the first answer for question 0.